# What detail am I missing trying to make a ajax page crawlable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I think I'm missing some detail trying to get google to index my ajax (gwt) website.

I've followed this approach: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

If I try the address with _escaped_fragment= in the browser (e.g. http//foo/?_escaped_fragment=bar corresponding to http//foo/#!bar) I see my html/indexing friendly snapshot. However, when I try fetching http//foo/#!bar in the google webmaster tools, I still get the original JS page, not the snapshot, which I'm assuming means that the google bot isn't really understanding that he should get the _escaped_fragment_= version not the #! version.

I have included  on the original html.

What could I be doing wrong? Any tips on where to look would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: I cannot directly help you. But I as well created a ajax page and also having still some trouble with search engines: http://www.arda-maps.org So basically you should not use the hashbang or reduce it to a minimum. And as I said I still have issues with the meta tags even tho I use the dublin core. So the question is do you really need the hashbang and exclamation mark?

Comment: Yes, in GWT you are forced to do a single page app, so the hashbang is the only way to represent different "pages"

Comment: No @ClaudioCoelho you can use the [push state api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and not use hashbang, [example](https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/1883821) with activities and places

Comment: Thanks @RonanQuillevere. I didn't know that. But how do I  make the google bot ask for the html snapshot of the JS page given that nicer url. What's the alternative to using the hashbang to let google know to ask a snapshot?